# How to use entity framework inheritance?

Tags: .net, entity-framework

First off I'm a noob so please be gentle :-) I have a base object Company. I want to inherit this into a Customer object and a Vendor object. My problem starts with the fact that a given company can be a customer and a vendor at the same time. All the examples I have seen a use a property of the company and set it to either customer or vendor, but I can't do this. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Tony

**Edit for (I hope) clarity.**

stijn

Here is a simplified version of what I am working toward. I have three tables as described below in my db. I have created the model in visual studio and have created associations between the tables (on CompanyId) and tested and everything behaves as expected. When I remove the associations and inherit customer and vendor from company I get lots of errors. My assumptions: Company can be an object or inherited by customer or vendor. A given company can be both a customer and a vendor.

I am very new to entity framework, I started working with it about two weeks back and am still trying to understand the more advanced (for me) parts. Am I completely off base in the direction I am taking, or am I just missing something critical?

Company
-ID
-Name
-Adress
-City
-etc

Customer
-CustomerID
-Customer Specific Fields
-CompanyID

Vendor
-VendorID
-Vendor Specific Fields
-CompanyID

andrewWinn

In my first try I was able to interact with vendor by creating the object then querying for an instance (right word I think) and using it this Vendor.Company.Address = "123 Happy Trails". What I would like to be able to do instead is Vendor.Address = "123 Happy Trails" using inheritance.

Thanks to both of you guys for trying to help.

Comment: Tony - 

If you want some help, we are going to need to see some sort of code, either what you have tried, and hopefully, pseudo code of what you would like to see.

Comment: this is merely a guess as you don't supply much information, but at first sight: build your Company class by composition, ie having a Customer and a Vendor member. If Customer and Vendor have a lot in common, they can still inherit one base class, but not Company.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem. I was using an existing database. The tables I were trying to use all had auto increment primary keys. They needed to auto increment turned off and 1:1 relationships defined in the database. Once I made these changes I was able to make inheritance behave exactly as I wanted.

T